# What is a single word for a "generic place something is mentioned in"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If X *mentions* Y, then that Y is *mentioned in* X.

For example, if a post mentions a user, then that user is mentioned in a post.

Or, if a comment mentions a company, then that company is mentioned in a comment.

Another way to consider it is a:
1. Story has many *mentions*, a User has many _______.?

Is *mention* reflective here? Does it work both ways?

Other synonyms to mention are `cited` and `referenced`

Comment: Can you use 'reference' for the word?

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cite *cited* might be of interest to you but it does more than mention a person but references a position/theory/argument of a person or a story

Comment: reference and cited are both synonyms (ish) for "mention". I'd like a single word for _the place the mentioning was done_. In my context, the person can be either mentioned in a Post (Story) or a Comment or a Link or a Picture...

Comment: A person can't be referenced, cited, mentioned or anything in a standard picture or link, right (tags notwithstanding)? So, from a programming perspective, you're saying they're *associated*, but a case can be made for there being a *referential* aspect too.

Comment: I would argue that a picture *pictures* or *shows* a person.

Comment: The expression '[Even Alatar] gets a mention' is idiomatic, and may be tweaked to  '[Even Alatar and Pallando] get a mention'. 'Alatar gets quite a few mentions' also seems quite acceptable, but 'Alatar has quite a few mentions' seems less idiomatic and 'Alatar gets/has 37 mentions' even less idiomatic.